# how to login using facebook and gmail in cakephp using cake DC

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

Iam new to cakePHP framework this is my first app using this coding style.
My Problem is this when I try to access facebook login link provided by cakeDC plugin my application is always redirecting to the normal login page

I have set my users.php in config file like this

```
return [
    'Users.Social.login' => true,
    'OAuth.providers.facebook.options.clientId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'OAuth.providers.facebook.options.clientSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',

    'OAuth.providers.google.options.clientId' => 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'OAuth.providers.google.options.clientSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    //etc
];
```

Any help guys, I am stacked

Comment: When I check other links generated by cakeDC i figured that are preceded by /users/user/xxxxxxx, But for facebook login ang gmail login only /auth/facebook or /auth/google appear to url is this a problem. Please Help

Comment: When I try to inspect my url request I found that /auth/facebook and /auth/google return [HTTP 1.1/ 302 xxx found] when trying to find out more about this error I find a trick that says abou mod_security in apache but I can't figure out to deal whith it please help me guys?